# .htaccess weird redirect PHP MVC

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

For anyone interested this was solved very simply by putting the root of my site to the public folder, Rookie error.

Hello ive just finished setting a website, and i am getting a weird redirect issue. When i first type in the URL https://project-wheels.co.uk when it gets to the site it redirects to  https://project-wheels.co.uk/public. This still works fine as this is where the project index is.

My directory is as follows
Application [folder]
public [folder]
.htaccess

Inside this first .ht access is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Then inside the public folder i have another htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The index file in the public folder starts the mvc application etc.

I used the mini-master template and i have no experience at all with htaccess files other than these.

To give a little more information this website is actually hosted as a Addon domain and is routed to a folder in the public_html folder of the root, Im not sure if this makes any difference.

Thank you in advance 
Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this on your first `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, Its really strange because sometimes it doesn't do it and other times it does. Am i missing a step to changing the htaccess, I dont need to do another step other than just doing FTP straight to server ?

Ah i also forgot to put in the second htaccess (inside public) 

At the bottom i also have

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}     [L,R=301]